# Xamarin Android Audio DSP

Tags: android, audio, xamarin.android, signal-processing, fft

I am looking for a audio DSP or FFT library which I can use for Xamarin, first and foremost Android, but iOS but also be cool.

I tried using Superpowered, but they only provide a static library which I can not link in the project.
I also tried using JTransforms, which unfortunately wont succesfully bind and is also not an android java library (only general android seem to work, according to xamarin documentation).

At first I tried using Xamarin Android Visualizer, but I want to be able to record/listen for sound and perform audio analysis "simultanously", without playing it back.

So, does anybody know a library, nuget or anything? I am really clueless.

Comment: Is this resolved? I also need solution for this.

Comment: Hi @Rikku Porta
Did you finally found a solution?
I have a similar need for a client: record noise from the microphone of the Android device, and display the related spectrogram.
I've seen that Scichart has done a realtime audio analyzer on Android (https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=yU05fsgOYO4), but it doesn't seem to be available on Xamarin.

Comment: No, I didn't find a solution and I dropped Xamarin in favor of a native android app

Answer (score 1):

[Bass](http://bass.radio42.com/)

Is a really good library that I have used cross platform in Xamarin. I built a very basic 'oscilloscope' display to accompany audio playback for a marketing app, but I think that you can get the data in different formats for processing. You would incorporate the Jar + additional libraries if you want non-core features.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how Bryon Baker used Superpowered with Xamarin: http://superpowered.com/working-with-audio-in-xamarin-with-superpowered-audio-engine

Comment: Hi, this is only valid for iOS. Superpowered is not a dynamic library (at least it seems so) and thus it cannot be imported for Android